# How to run a function when a variable is accessed/read in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: debugging, hooks, variables

I'm trying to find a way to run a function whenever a specific variable is accessed or read in Emacs Lisp. I want to know which functions are using this variable, but I don't know them beforehand.

I'm aware of the `add-variable-watcher` function, which can be used to monitor when a variable is modified. However, this doesn't seem to cover the case when the variable is simply accessed or read without being modified.

Is there a way to run a "get" function or a hook whenever a variable is read in Emacs Lisp, without knowing which functions are using the variable?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the C function `eval_sub`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: If the variable is one you created (e.g. for your own package or other code), consider replacing its occurrences with a nullary function call that just returns the variable's value. ;-)

Comment: `M-x rgrep` is your friend -- just search the code if you want to know what code is using some symbol.  (It's *possible* that something will generate the name in a less-obvious way, but for the most part names are not obfuscated and we can leverage basic tooling for things like this).